# Setting Up Quad9 DNS service on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns

I want to set up Quad9 DNS Service on my 76 Computer running Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm wondering if anyone has done this, and if successful, if they can give me step by step instructions.  Thank you.  Oh, I don'w know if this is an issue but I do use a VPN.